# Using NSPopupButton and Cocoa Binding with predefined class

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a `NSPopupButton`. Also, I have a `NSArray` of objects with `ClassA` type, which is a predefined class and I don't have access to its code.

I'm trying to populate a `NSPopupButton` with this `NSArray`, so I used Cocoa Bindings. I set the content to the array, so for each item, it will use `-description` for the item label. But I want to use my own labels. How can I do this?

I already tried using "Content Values" alongside my custom `NSValueTransform`, that converts `ClassA` objects to `NSString`, but that didn't helped; it seems that my transform never called. I can't also apply my `NSValueTransform` to "Content" binding, because that breaks the "Selected Objects" (it passes the string instead of the actual object). For fixing this, I filled the "Content Objects" with proper values, but that didn't work, either.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of your bindings setup?

Comment: It's going to be easier to just forego bindings and just have an `IBOutlet` connected to the popup button and an `IBAction` for its selection.  That way you can analyze the array and populate the popup button as you see fit.